# Cannot clear HTML/Javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here is my javascript code:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;


 particle = [];
 particleCount = 0,
gravity = 0.3,
colors = [
  '#f44336', '#e91e63', '#9c27b0', '#673ab7', '#3f51b5',
  '#2196f3', '#03a9f4', '#00bcd4', '#009688', '#4CAF50',
  '#8BC34A', '#CDDC39', '#FFEB3B', '#FFC107', '#FF9800',
  '#FF5722', '#795548'
];


function drawparticles(){
        for( var i = 0; i < 250; i++){


particle.push({
    x : width/2,
    y : height/2,
    boxW : randomRange(5,15),
    boxH : randomRange(5,15),
    size : randomRange(2,6),

    spikeran:randomRange(3,5),

    velX :randomRange(-8,8),
    velY :randomRange(-50,-10),

    angle :convertToRadians(randomRange(0,360)),
    color:colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
    anglespin:randomRange(-0.2,0.2),

    draw : function(){


        context.save();
            context.translate(this.x,this.y);
            context.rotate(this.angle);
        context.fillStyle=this.color;
        context.beginPath();
        // drawStar(0, 0, 5, this.boxW, this.boxH);
    context.fillRect(this.boxW/2*-1,this.boxH/2*-1,this.boxW,this.boxH);
        context.fill();
                context.closePath();
        context.restore();
        this.angle += this.anglespin;
        this.velY*= 0.999;
        this.velY += 0.3;

        this.x += this.velX;
        this.y += this.velY;
            if(this.y < 0){
        this.velY *= -0.2;
            this.velX *= 0.9;
        };
        if(this.y > height){
        this.anglespin = 0;
        this.y = height;
        this.velY *= -0.2;
            this.velX *= 0.9;
        };
            if(this.x > width ||this.x< 0){

        this.velX *= -0.5;
        };



    },




    });


   }


}



function drawScreen(){

for( var i = 0; i < particle.length; i++){
    particle[i].draw();

}


}



function update(){

    var fps = 120;

    context.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    drawScreen();

    setTimeout(function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }, 1000 / fps);
}

update();

 function clearparticles(content){
    content.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 }

 function randomRange(min, max){
    return min + Math.random() * (max - min );
 }

 function randomInt(min, max){
    return Math.floor(min + Math.random()* (max - min + 1));
 }

function convertToRadians(degree) {
    return degree*(Math.PI/180);
 }
```

The function clearparticles is where I try to clear the html/javascript particles on my canvas. However this doesn't seem to be working at all.
It seems I get the following error: **Cannot read property 'clearRect' of undefined**

I cannot think of anything else to get it working. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is the HTML CODE (test code):

```
<style>
    html, body  {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          cursor: default;   text-align: center;

          font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    }

    canvas  {
                        pointer-events:none;
                position: absolute;
                left:0;
                top:0;
                z-index:0;
                border:0px solid #000;
    }
</style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>

   </head>
     <body>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="confetti2.js"></script>
     <button onclick="drawparticles()">Spawn</button>
      <button onclick="clearparticles()">Clear</button>

  </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: you don't include the code where you call clearparticles

Comment: Show us the code which calls the clearparticles() method.  You are probably not supplying a valid canvas as an argument to that function.

Comment: Yeah sorry, It's just a simple test: 

       `<button onclick="clearparticles()">Clear</button> `
and I call the main script with `<button onclick="drawparticles()">Spawn</button>` I put the whole code in OP

Comment: Now it should be obvious. The function expects `content` as an argument. You don’t supply an argument, hence `content` is undefined.

Comment: Yeah, I thought this `context = canvas.getContext("2d");` defined content? Sorry new to JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML code contains

```
 <button onclick="clearparticles()">Clear</button>
```

When you click that button, it invokes the method `clearparticles()`. But that doesn't exist. It is not able to find that function. What you have is

```
function clearparticles(content){
    content.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

This function expects an argument, but you don't provide any data from the onclick event. You can solve it by removing the "content" argument. To clear the rectangle, you only have to call the `clearRect(...)` function of your drawing context (more info: [`MDN - CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) )

Since you already have a context as global variable,

```
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

You can simply use the next to solve your problem

```
function clearparticles(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Or you can of course provide an argument in the `onclick` attribute. But that is not a clean solution.

Comment: Yeah, I actually had that originally. I am using that again to double test it. It removes all the errors out of the console.log however it's not working, here my the test site: http://icarus.milescollier.com/index2.html

Comment: I have to review your code. Apparently you're using `setTimeout(function () {requestAnimationFrame(update); }, 1000 / fps);` which draws the particles in the array each interval. Just add a new line: `particle = []` in the clearparticles() function to clear the memory. Then there are no draw-calls for each particles anymore when updating the canvas.

Comment: Oh my, it makes so much since! Thanks a bunch, never thought of doing that. It looks perfect now - even got it so it fades in and out now. I love you.